# How to hide the border around child window

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, childwindow

I have a child Window , and I am displaying it from the code behind as below:

```
ChildPhotoViewer PhotoViewer = new ChildPhotoViewer();
                PhotoViewer.DataContext = selectedPhoto;
                PhotoViewer.Title = selectedPhoto.strTitle.ToString();
                PhotoViewer.Show();
```

But While Displaying the child window I am getting the Close Button and a Border thickness arround the Window.

I am able to hide the Close Button but is there a way to hide the thickness(Border) across the child window.

**Edit:**

![alt text][1]

In the Image , there is border arround image after Collpasing the Close button and making

```
PhotoViewer.Title = null;
PhotoViewer.HasCloseButton = false;
```

I want to get rid of that Rectangular Border.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Have you tried:-</strike>

```
PhotoViewer.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
```

**Edit**

Perhaps you are refering to the title block across the top of the window?

```
PhotoViewer.Title = null;
PhotoViewer.HasCloseButton = false;
```

**Edit**

Third attempt.

The template for `ChildWindow` place the content in border with a 7 pixel margin.  This also has an outer border which has a White background.  That is what you are seeing in the image.  The only way to eliminate it is to copy the ChildWindow template and edit it.

Comment: @Subhen:  Are you refering to the title block above the child window?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by the Border.

If you have a look at the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow) you can see there is a border (with a thickness of 1) around the edge of the entire window that can be altered like Anthony mentions.

However there is also the window Chrome which in the default template has a number of borders. To change the thickness of these borders you will need to create a style without the borders being present.